# Not able to get all values in ListView in android

Tags: android, listview

I am creating a list in android. That is I am fetching list from the server and adding it to an ArrayList.After that, I have created an adapter to show the list but the problem is that I have total two values in the list but ListView showing me only 1 item. I have checked a lot. I checked adapter. It got total 2 items but showing only 1. Why this problem. Please help.

//Fetching list from server

```
  JSONArray askArray = response.getJSONArray("data");

                        if (askArray.length() > 0) {

                            final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> cameraList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                            for (int i = 0; i < askArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject cameraObject = askArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                //Log.e("TAG", "onResponse: "+cameraObject.getString("description"));
                                HashMap<String, String> store = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                store.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, cameraObject.getString("description"));
                                cameraList.add(store);
                            }
```

//Adapter of listview

```
    public class AdapterTermsNConditions extends BaseAdapter {


private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
private Context context;
AskFormFragment askFormFragment;
HashMap<String, String> officeList1;


public AdapterTermsNConditions(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d, AskFormFragment askFormFragment) {
    activity = a;
    data = d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.askFormFragment = askFormFragment;

}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_terms_conditions, parent, false);

    Log.e("position", +position+"");

    TextView txtTerms = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTerms);


    officeList1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    officeList1 = data.get(position);
    Log.e("termsList", officeList1.toString() +  "" +position);


    txtTerms.setText(officeList1.get(AskFormFragment.KEY_DESCRIPTION));

    Log.e("TAG", "terms_size: "+data.toString() );

    return itemView;
}


}
```

Comment: `//Adapter of listview` you didn't show the adapter code, only 1 method.

Comment: share your whole `Adapter of listview` class with question

Comment: check updated code

Comment: check updated code @NileshRathod

Comment: check updated code @VladMatvienko

Comment: Try to use officeList1 = getItem(position); instead of data.get(position);

Comment: It is asking for hashmap not object not working @Vodet

Comment: can you print data.size() in your get view and let me the size ?

Comment: Can you try to replace your itemView with convertView

Comment: I think bellow answer will work.....

Comment: It is working fine if I increase size of listview otherwise not working fine

Comment: Are you sure something isn't overlapping the top of your `ListView`, hiding the first item? Maybe a `Toolbar`, `AppBarLayout`, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You can try bellow like

1. Fetching list from server

   ```
      List<CamaraModel> listValue= new ArrayList<>();

       Array askArray = response.getJSONArray("data");
       if (askArray.length() > 0) {


         for (int i = 0; i < askArray.length(); i++) {
           JSONObject cameraObject = askArray.getJSONObject(i);
           //Log.e("TAG", "onResponse: "+cameraObject.getString("description"));
           CamaraModel model = new CamaraModel();
           model.setDescription(cameraObject.getString("description"));
           listValue.add(model);
       }
   }

   CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(AccountBalanceInfo.this, listValue);

   listView.setAdapter(adapter);
   ```
2. You should use model like

   ```
   public class CamaraModel {
    private String description;

    public String getDescription() {
    return description;
    }

     public void setDescription(String description) {
      this.description = description;
      }
   }
   ```
3. create layout xml name test_row.xml & paste

   ```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >  

      <TextView
         android:id="@+id/tv_descripton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"         
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="description"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"/>    

     </LinearLayout>
   ```
4. At last you use adapter like

   ```
           public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CamaraModel> {

          // View lookup cache

      private  class ViewHolder {

         TextView description;


      }



      public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, List<CamaraModel> loandAmomount) {

         super(context, R.layout.test_row, loandAmomount);

     }



    @Override

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       // Get the data item for this position

       CamaraModel model = getItem(position);

       CustomListViewAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag

       if (convertView == null) {

           viewHolder = new CustomListViewAdapter.ViewHolder();

           LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

           convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_row, parent, false);

           viewHolder.description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);


           convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

       } else {

           viewHolder = (CustomListViewAdapter.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

       }

       // Populate the data into the template view using the data object

       viewHolder.description.setText(model.getDescription());


       // Return the completed view to render on screen

       if (position%2== 0) {
           convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F5EEE5"));
       }else{

           convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
       }

       return convertView;

     }

    }
   ```